# ERROR: CANNOT PARALLELIZE AN UPDATE STATEMENT THAT UPDATES THE DISTRIBUTION COLUMNS

Tags: etl, talend, greenplum, hawq

When trying to copy data from source (MSSQLSERVER) TO target (greenplum database) using talend  ETL server.

Description: When executing an UPDATE statement to GreenPlum, the mentioned error is thrown.

**GIVEN**

No of records fetching to target is  ~ 0.3 million

**Update is failing with error**

```
 ERROR: CANNOT PARALLELIZE AN UPDATE STATEMENT THAT UPDATES THE DISTRIBUTION COLUMNS current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Any help on it would be much appreciated

Solution i tried :

When ON_ERROR_ROLLBACK is enabled, psql will issue a SAVEPOINT before every command you send to greenplum

```
gpadmin=# \set ON_ERROR_ROLLBACK interactive
```

But after that we tried running the same Job and it did not solved the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) Update is not supported in Hawq.
2) Update is only supported to heap but not AO table in GPDB.
GPDB/HAWQ are used as data warehouse/BI and data exploration purpose.

Comment: In GPDB  When i am using  Heap storage  syntax like this CREATE TABLE foo (a int, b text) DISTRIBUTED BY (a);

Comment: Also Job Finishes with Hang  then  after some times it is throwing the error

Comment: you can't update distribution key. it is how MPP works.

Comment: Update is supported on AO tables, since those are Append Optimized :)

Comment: @BalazsGunics so table storage should be AO instead heap.? then update will work on it

Comment: I have to update ~0.3 million rows on each job run. when i am trying to execute the job . No rows is updating due to ERROR: CANNOT PARALLELIZE AN UPDATE STATEMENT THAT UPDATES THE DISTRIBUTION COLUMNS

Comment: distribution key is used to decide which segment should store your table rows. It doesn't make any sense to "update" distribution key.  Why would you change distribution key? are you trying to shuffling data?

Comment: salesorder is primary key as well as distribution key. For update, schema should have key.